# I removed a post and got a -8 reputation loss

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

I posted an answer to a question that another user made comments about not being helpful. The answer didn't have any upvotes or downvotes, so I just decided to remove the answer.

What I don't understand is: Why would I lose 8 reputation points for this? See the last entry below.

-9     today:

| change | time | action | post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +2 | 41 mins ago | removed | c++ Why is my date parsing not threadsafe? |
| -1 | 57 mins ago | downvoted | When to make a type non-movable in C++11? |
| -2 | 1 hour ago | downvote | const reference and creating copy |
| -8 | 18 mins ago | removed | const reference and creating copy |

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18652535) has a *score* of 0; you had one upvote and one downvote:

[image: post votes]

You had gained 8 points from this post (upvote: 10 points, downvote: -2 points), which you lost again when you self-deleted the post.

You'd regain the points if you undelete the post.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the 8 back? Maybe undelete?

Comment: @bjackfly: yes, undeleting would re-instate the 8 points.

Answer (score 4):

You had one upvote on that answer, so you earned 10 rep. Then today someone downvoted the answer (10 - 2 = 8), then you deleted the answer, so you lose another 8 rep.

Also 0 *score* on the post doesn't mean always 0 *votes*. That can be (+2 | -2) or (+1 | -1) or (+N | -N)